# regex_search matching unspecified text

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I've been using Boost::regex and Boost::regex_search and found that when I run the regex

```
\\<(\\w+\\-?\\w+)\\>
```

These all get matched like normal

```
BitcoinicaHacker> Who wants free bitcoins courtesy of bitcoinica?
<grepix> who doesn't!
<BitcoinicaHacker> post your btc addr
<nanotube> i think bitcoinica wants free bitcoins courtesy of bitcoinica
```

But lines like this also get matched

```
--> peacekeep3r (~peacekeep@chello084114169104.2.15.vie.surfer.at) has joined #bitcoin
<-- Raccoon has quit (Changing host)
--> Raccoon (bismuth@unaffiliated/raccoon) has joined #bitcoin
```

This is rather confusing since I specifically asked it to find a left angle bracket then text that might have a dash and then a right angle bracket.

Update 2:

Thanks to Ωmega for helping me find the best solution:    `<(\\w+(?:\\-\\w+)*)>`

Update:

Either

```
<(\\w+\\-?\\w+)> or <([^-<>]+[^<>]*)> works for my purposes.
```

I forgot to remove the escape slashes.

Comment: Could this be related to not using the starting and ending anchors? (^ and $)

Comment: I just tried with that and it no longer matches anything. I tried also just the ^ at the beginning, but that didn't work either. AFAIK those have to do with beginning of the input string and ending so if I put those on it would be the same as using regex_match and I would have to supply everything else that might be in the line also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use regex `<([^-<>]+[^<>]*)>` which reads:

*Match content between `<` and `>` that starts with character other than `-`, `<`, or `>`, followed by any combination (also empty) of characters other than `<` or `>`.*

***Update:***

You may also consider to use regex `<((?!\\-\\-)[^<>]+)>` which reads:

*Match content between `<` and `>` that does not start with `--` and does not contain any `<` or `>`.*

Comment: Thanks. This works!

Mind explaining a bit as to why this works correctly and how it is better?

Comment: It makes sure the 2nd character is not `-`, which is part of `-->` and `<--`. The name on IRC can contain `-`, but I'm not sure if it can start with `-` - such user might escape the match.

Comment: @nhahtdh - you mean something like `<-this is a tag>`? I don't think that it is allowed to start with `-`, but it is up to OP to say... But I have updated my answer with an alterntive solution.

Comment: I just checked http://www.mirc.com/rfc2812.html , and the first character cannot be `-`. The name also cannot contain `<` or `>`.

Comment: So I just realized that I escaped my angle brackets, and without those it works perfectly as well.  
    '<(\\w+\\-?\\w+)> '
I can't get the code formatting in my comment to work >_>

Comment: @trippedoutfish - your regex would not work with one character tags, such as `<a>`, or multiple dash tags, such as `<a-b-c>`, unless you change the inside pattern to `(\\w+(?:\\-\\w+)*)`

Comment: @Ωmega - That does seem like the most elegant answer. Thanks for all the help.